# 6/8 at 60 BPM - not sure where the metronome fits in

Tags: time-signatures

I'm learning a piece of music on the guitar which is in 6/8, it says 57BPM - but for this question lets say **60bpm**

On YouTube I found a metronome click for 60 BPM in 6/8 time.

I'm slightly confused as to where the 60bpm fits in, in 6/8 time.  If I tap on beats 1 and 2 - I'm sure this is slower than 60bpm and when I tap every note of the within the bar - I'm finding is way faster than 60bpm?

On my own metronome I'm not sure what to set it, obviously if this was 1/4 note in 4/4 it would be fine - but with 6/8 I'm not sure at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the strong and weak beats in a bar of 6/8. You would have:

> **ONE** two three **four** five six

Which means you have the strong beat on one and then on four. So I suggest setting your metronome so that every tap of the metronome is on *one* then on *four* then on *one* of the second bar then on the *four* etc.. You'd say that a dotted quarter is at 60bpm. You would see this at the beginning of the score as such:

[image]

There are numerous free online metronomes, no need to search for a video on youtube, where you can do all kinds of things. Like you can have 6 beats, where the first and fourth ones are accented.

For some reason though, the video you provided has every single beat on the metronome (that is 6 per bar) and it has accented two of them. This is a good thing for a beginner

Comment: The video in question, however, has 40 dotted quarter notes per minute, not 60.  It's simply incorrect.

Comment: That video is indeed accenting 1 and 4, but at the wrong tempo. Why do people do this sort of thing? Ignorance is not bliss!

Comment: @Tim I suspect that it's because it's easier for digital metronome programmers to avoid the complication of having to consider the time signature when translating from "bpm" to the amount of time separating beats. Of course, it's particularly complicated because the unit of time given in the metronome marking isn't always the nominal "beat" of the time signature (6/8 is probably the most prominent example of that, but others are common).

Comment: @Tim - My answer tries to explain why people do this sort of thing - some music notation software will in fact tell you that you are at 60 bpm with the tempo in the video.

Answer (score 2):

The video you found is incorrect.

A metronome marking equates a number of beats per minute with a note value.  The note value is normally a dotted quarter note, as in the other answer, but it could also be the eighth note.  It will never be the quarter note.  But the video you've found, which purports to be at 60 beats per minute, has 60 *quarter notes* per minute.

This is of course equivalent to 120 eighth notes per minute or 40 dotted quarter notes per minute.  Neither of these is 60 beats per minute in 6/8 time.

> If I tap on beats 1 and 2 - I'm sure this is slower than 60bpm

You're right.  It's 40 bpm.

> and when I tap every note of the within the bar - I'm finding is way faster than 60bpm

It is.  It's 120 bpm.

Answer (score 0):

At least one music notation software, Musescore, actually treats the quarter note to have the definitive pulse, so assuming phoog's answer is correct and the video is at quarter note = 60 BPM or dotted quarter = 40 BPM, Musescore will in fact treat this as correct. This is at its most obvious in Musescore's Play Panel, which displays what Musescore treats as the BPM regardless of the actual meter or notated tempo of your piece at this point.

Comment: The existence of software that uses "bpm" incorrectly does not change the fact that the video is incorrect.  "Beat" does not universally mean "quarter note."  Also, you do not have to assume that my answer is correct; you can measure it.  I timed ten measures of that metronome track with a stopwatch, and it came out at exactly 30 seconds (0.5 minutes).  Ten measures of 6/8 is of course 60 eighth notes or 20 dotted quarters.  Dividing 60 eighths by 0.5 minutes yields 120 eighths per minute; 20 dotted quarters divided by 0.5 minutes is of course 40 dotted quarters per minute.